# finding what is adjacent to a selection in text

Tags: javascript, range, highlight

Suppose a viewer of some text on my web page selects a word.  I can catch the mouseup event, and create a JavaScript range based on the selection.  At this point there are two separate tasks I want to accomplish:

The first task is to enforce that the word is a whole word, and not just a fragment of a word.  So I need to find out if the word has whitespace before and after.  To do that, it would make sense to find where the range starts and ends and broaden it - decrement the 'startOffset' by 1, increment the endoffset by 1, create a new range based on that, and find out if the text in it starts and ends with whitespace.

(In practice the task is more complicated because the selected word could be the first or last word of text, in which case there might be no whitespace before or after it, and also, it might have a tag sandwich around it such as the BOLD or ITALIC tag pairs.)

So the first question is, how do I get the first and last position of the existing range so that I can alter them when I create the new range?

(In my test example I have an ARTICLE tag with an id, and within that are a few paragraphs of text.)

The second task is, given the coordinates of a range, to select text based on those coordinates.  So if the user selected the word "Eagle", which for example starts at position 30, then 4 days later, he can visit the site, and I can display the original text with "Eagle" at position 30 highlighted.

```js
var hp_globalRange;
var hp_CurrentSel;
var hp_startOffset = 0;
var hp_endOffset = 0;
var hp_seltext;
var hp_selhtml;
var hp_pending = false;

// *********************
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!window.CurrentSelection) {
    hp_CurrentSel = {}
  }
  //define the selector object
  hp_CurrentSel.Selector = {}

  //get the current selection
  hp_CurrentSel.Selector.getSelected = function() {
      var sel = '';
      if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection()
      } else if (document.getSelection) {
        sel = document.getSelection()
      } else if (document.selection) {
        sel = document.selection.createRange()
      }
      return sel;
    }
    // *********************
  hp_CurrentSel.Selector.mouseup = YeMouseUp;
  $("#ArticleToHighlightRFS").bind("mouseup", hp_CurrentSel.Selector.mouseup);
  $("#ArticleToHighlightRFS").bind("mousedown", function() {
    hp_pending = true;
  });
  $('body').bind("mouseup", function() {
    if (!hp_pending) {
      return;
    }
    YeMouseUp();
  });
});
  // +++++++++++++
function printDocumentFragment(docfrag) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(docfrag);
  return (div.innerHTML);
}
// ********** END GLOBALS **************//
function isSelectionOK(hp_seltext) {
  var arr;
  var thelen;
  var trimmed = hp_seltext.trim();
  thelen = trimmed.length;
  if (thelen > 100) {
    console.error("Error: the maximum size of a selection is 100 characters, yours is " + thelen + ".");
    return false;
  }
  if (thelen < 1) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}


// +++++++++++++
function YeMouseUp() {
  hp_pending = false;
  hp_seltext = "";
  hp_selhtml = "";
  var pos;
  var containingRange = document.createRange();
  var articleNode = document.getElementById('ArticleToHighlightRFS');
  var containingText = '';
  var containingHTML = '';
  $('span.selectedText').contents().unwrap();

  var st = hp_CurrentSel.Selector.getSelected();

  containingRange.selectNode(articleNode);
  containingRange.setEnd(st.focusNode, st.focusOffset);
  console.log("st.focusNode=" + st.focusNode + ", st.focusOffset=" + st.focusOffset); // !!!!
  containingText = containingRange.toString();


  var docfrag = containingRange.cloneContents();
  containingHTML = printDocumentFragment(docfrag);

  hp_globalRange = st.getRangeAt(0);

  var newNode = document.createElement("span");
  newNode.setAttribute("class", "selectedText");
  try {
    hp_globalRange.surroundContents(newNode);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error: `you need to highlight a selection that does not end in middle of a formatted word.   If you highlight the blanks at each side of the word, along with the word(s), it will probably solve this problem. Please try again.");
    return;
  }
  //
  hp_selhtml = newNode.innerHTML;
  hp_seltext = newNode.innerText;
  if (!isSelectionOK(hp_seltext)) {
    return false;
  }
  newNode.setAttribute("title", hp_seltext);


  if (window.getSelection) {
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    document.selection.empty();
  }


  pos = containingHTML.length;

  if (hp_seltext.length < 1) {
    return;
  }


  console.log("text is [" + hp_seltext + "] and html is [" + hp_selhtml + "]");

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h2>Please highlight any word (or words) in the lines below...</h2>
<div>
  <article id="ArticleToHighlightRFS">
    The rain in spain<br />
    Falls mainly in the plain<br />
    Be <b>bold</b> but not arrogant.
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your test example?

Comment: I've edited my post to add my code, as requested by evolutionxbox.

Comment: It seems like you have a large task on your hands. You might want to consider reducing this question down to it's absolute minimum.

Comment: I think I found my answer in http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/JavaScript-DOM-Ranges.id-292301.html .  But to simplify what I'm asking for, given a range, how do you extend it on both ends so that it includes one extra text character at the start, and at the end.